# Display chosen option from select to the title of another select

Tags: javascript, html

I cant figure out how to make it so the option chosen in the first select menu changes the title of the second select menu. Any help? This is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">First:</label>
<select id="select">
  <option value="1">Apple</option>
<option value="2">Orange</option>
<option value="3">Peach</option>
</select>
</div>

<br>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" id="output">Second:</label>
<select>
  <option value="1">Pineapple</option>
<option value="2">Grape</option>
<option value="3">Pear</option>
</select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var e = document.getElementById("select");
var output = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: Define "title" of the second select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var list1 = document.getElementById("select1");
var list2Title = document.getElementById("output");

list1.addEventListener("change", function(){
  output.textContent = this.options[this.selectedIndex].textContent;
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">First:</label>
<select id="select1">
  <option value="1">Apple</option>
<option value="2">Orange</option>
<option value="3">Peach</option>
</select>
</div>

<br>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" id="output">Second:</label>
<select id="select2">
  <option value="1">Pineapple</option>
<option value="2">Grape</option>
<option value="3">Pear</option>
</select>
</div>
```